# Multiple submit actions with multiple submit buttons in asp net core razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, form-submit, submit-button

I have a razor page with a form and multiple submit buttons. with each button I want to start a different Post action in my codebehind file. so this is in my cshtml page:

```
<form class="form" method="post" >
    <input type="submit" value="Test1" formaction="Button1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test2" formaction="Button2" />
</form>
```

and this in my cshtml.cs file:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Button1(IFormCollection data)
{
//my code
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Button2(IFormCollection data)
{
//my code
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. when I submit I get a 404 error:

**This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44366/Mutations/Button1
HTTP ERROR 404**

The correct URL should be: https://localhost:44366/Mutations/Test

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Because you are a project in `Razor`, the routing rules in `Razor` are different from `MVC` projects, you can change your code as follows:

Your cshtml.cs file:

```
 public IActionResult OnPostButton1(IFormCollection data)
    {
        //...
    }

   
    public IActionResult OnPostButton2(IFormCollection data)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Your cshtml page:

```
<form class="form" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Test1" asp-page-handler="Button1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Test2"  asp-page-handler="Button2"/>
</form>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: There is a session exception (ModelState.IsValid == false because of that) with this approach despite me not configuring session at all. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You must assign different routes (that match your `formaction`) to both actions:

```
[HttpPost("button1")]
public IActionResult Button1(IFormCollection data)
{
//my code
}

[HttpPost("button2")]
public IActionResult Button2(IFormCollection data)
{
//my code
}
```